# Validate NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am validating an NSString to ensure that the string does not contain apostrophes.

The code I'm using to do this is

```
NSCharacterSet * invalidNumberSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"'"];
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
NSString  * scannerResult;
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:invalidNumberSet intoString:&scannerResult];
if(![string isEqualToString:scannerResult])
{
    return 2;
}
```

Returning 2 represents an error.  This code works, except for the case where the string is an apostrophe.

To get around this issue, I added the following code above the preceding block.

```
if([string isEqualToString:@"'"]);
{
    return 2;
}
```

This code is evaluating to true, regardless of the input. I need to either prevent the first block from crashing with the input of ', or get the second block to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: @Chris: You can build on Chuck's answer as well if you ever have a set of characters that you need to check for. So, if you build up an NSCharacterSet with all the illegal characters you can do something like if (([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invalidSet]).location != NSNotFound) // do something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no logical reason why the `isEqualToString:` test should always succeed. If that's your actual, copy-pasted code, you must have an error somewhere else in the function.

At any rate, it would be much simpler to test if the location of `[string rangeOfString:@"'"]` is `NSNotFound`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple!  I used 
if([string rangeOfString:@"'"].location != NSNotFound)
 {
  return 2;
 }

To replace the above code.